# How to search in files content using terminal emulator?

Tags: terminal

I have tablet with android 4.4.2. The tablet is rooted. I want to search for a string in the files in the whole file system. I tried to use the 'find' command but it didn't work. What command i can use to implement this search and is it possible to install 'find' command line tool on android?

Comment: Have you tried `grep`? FYI, this is more of a *nix question than  Android app itself. You might need to install BusyBox for `grep` or `find`.

Comment: How to use `grep` to search for string? I tried this but it didn't work: `grep -i "serach string" /*`

Comment: What was the error? If it says grep wasn't found out or such, you probably need BusyBox. Did you try the man page for grep for learning the correct usage?Try googling "man grep"

Comment: I think i am using wrong command parameters. I will search google for grep command usage

Answer (score 1):

I found that this command is working: `grep -r "search string" /`

Comment: Use `grep -r -I` if you want to search only in text files and not in binary files (executable, audio, video etc.).